# Return simulated pricing result

Tags: r, random

I am quite new to R and try to do a pricing simulation. The goal is to have a vector with length n, that gives a percentage for the coupon that will be received. When I use print, I get exactly the result I want. However, for my subsequent calculations I cannot proceed with results in print format. I tried replacing it with return but this just gives me one result.

Any input is appreciated.

(package used for rgpd is POT)

```
bond_coupon <- function(n, l) {
     events <- rpois(n, l) #simulates the rate of arrival according to a Poisson process
     for (i in 1:length(events)){
         cat <- rgpd(events[i], loc=1000, scale=100, shape=1) #simulates the severance of each event
         if(events[i]>1){
             coupon <- prod(1-((cat-1000)/cat))
         } else if(events[i]==1){
             coupon<- 1-((cat-1000)/cat)
         } else{
             coupon<- 1.00
         }
         print(coupon)
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `coupon` is overwritten at each iteration of loop, hence `return` only returns the last one.

You could create a vector `coupon` and fill it at each iteration:

```
bond_coupon <- function(n, l) {
  events <- rpois(n, l) #simulates the rate of arrival according to a Poisson process
  coupon = numeric(length(events))
  for (i in 1:length(events)){
    cat <- rgpd(events[i], loc=1000, scale=100, shape=1) #simulates the severance of each event
    if(events[i]>1){
      coupon[i] <- prod(1-((cat-1000)/cat))
    } else if(events[i]==1){
      coupon[i]<- 1-((cat-1000)/cat)
    } else{
      coupon[i]<- 1.00
    }
  }
  return(coupon)
}
```

Alternatively you could delegate creation and looping to `apply` family of functions:

```
bond_coupon <- function(n, l) {
  #simulates the rate of arrival according to a Poisson process
  events <- rpois(n, l)
  
  coupon <- sapply(X = seq_along(events), FUN = function(i) {
      #simulates the severance of each event
      cat <- rgpd(events[i], loc = 1000, scale = 100, shape = 1)
      
      if (events[i] > 1) {
        prod(1 - ((cat - 1000) / cat))
      } else if (events[i] == 1) {
        1 - ((cat - 1000) / cat)
      } else {
        1.00
      }
    }
  )
  return(coupon)
}
```